# Appending Fontastic Icons to SVG with D3.js

Tags: d3.js, icons, fontastic

I spend a lot of my time working with FontAwesome/LinearIcons and d3.js - 
https://medium.com/@bryony_17728/d3-js-linearicons-and-font-awesome-887548662162

But this is the first time working with custom Fontastic font and something odd is going on.

I've got the stylesheet link and referencing direct in the HTML is working perfectly:

```
 <span class="icon-01"></span>
 <i class="icon-02"></i>
```

I then add a text element in the same way I would FontAwesome/Linear Icons (written in HTML for ease of testing):

```
  <svg width="100" height="40">
  <text x="20" y="20" style="font-family: untitled-font-3">\ue907</text>
  </svg>
```

I get icons but all of them!

[image: Results - 2 xleft hand icons are the span and i tags]

Any ideas?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could set up a [mcve] demonstrating your issue.

Comment: I'm not sure the client will be happy with me sharing their font.

Comment: Lots of examples in the medium article though.  What I really need it to find someone who has done this before???

Comment: Lots of examples, but not with Fontastic; Also, those examples don't change the fact that we cannot debug your code with the info you shared: without a [MCVE] there is little we can do.

Comment: Too true...  https://codepen.io/bmpms/pen/qeJxQM

Comment: Also just updated it so that you have the original svg and text in the html AND a d3 script at the bottom....   Probably something obvious but it escapes me...

Comment: As you can clearly see in your example, `\ue907` is treated as five separate characters, generating one icon for each one of them. Just do "\" and you'll see the "edit" icon. This PUA is not working. I suggest you contact the Fontastic team directly.

Comment: Thank you.  That was obvious!  I'll get back if Fontastic solve the problem for me..

Comment: Meanwhile any other ideas welcome.